# rails 4-- accessing api data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a sample rails 4 app and I'm unclear about something. I want to access an external API to pull data on sports news via an ajax call.

So for example if you have a list of teams in the `teams#index` view, when you click on one team a widget will get populated with the latest results / scores for that team-- the results info is provided by an external API service, not the local database.

Do I need to create a controller for this service to allow the rails ajax request to have a local endpoint? Should the actual request mechanism happen in this controller? or would it be better to build a helper for the data request and call that from the controller?

On the other hand it's possible to do it all via javascript in the browser.

Thanks-- I realize there's a dozen ways to do things in rails, I'm just unclear on the "right" way to handle this type of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to do this with a helper module that you can unit test independently.  To give you a similar, trivial example, here's a module that you could use to wrap the Gravatar API:

```
# /lib/gravatar.rb
module Gravatar
  def self.exists email
    url = self.image_url email

    url = url + '?d=404'

    response = HTTParty.get url

    return response.code != 404
  end

  def self.image_url email, size=nil
    gravatar_id = self.gravatar_id email

    size_url = size ? '?s=' + size.to_s : ''

    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png" + size_url
  end

  def self.gravatar_id email
    Digest::MD5::hexdigest(email.downcase)
  end
end
```

Then, you can make a call to `Gravatar::image_url` as necessary.  If you wanted to be able to access a Gravatar image via an ajax call, you could simply wrap it in a controller:

```
# /app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb
class Api::UsersController < Api::BaseController
  def gravatar_for_user_id
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    render plain: Gravatar::image_url user.email, :status => 200
  end
end
```

This model can be applied to whatever external APIs you need to hit, and modularizing your interface will always make unit testing more straightforward.

Comment: @kid_drew-- I am having a problem with this returning an `unintialized constant` error from the controller. I have a `/lib/dataconnect.rb` module, with the module name `Dataconnect` -- calling `Dataconnect::getNews` from the controller. Are the `/lib/` modules auto loaded?

Comment: /lib needs to be added to your autoload_paths config in application.rb: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`